# Facebook API shows incorrect number of recent updates/posts

Tags: facebook

We are using the Facebook API to show the recent 15 updates in an application. But the recent 15 updates are shown for few IDs (Facebook IDs) and for some it shows 3 or 4.
It varies from ID to ID.

I have tested this by updating some 15 posts, likes, et c., with a Facebook ID but the recent updates shown are only 3. I am getting these updates from "FEEDS".